# How can I tell when a program argument should be a configuration variable?

Tags: programming-practices

In simple cases I can see right away which direction to go. If I'm passing  a working directory to my program, and it's the same for the vast majority of the runs, make it a configuration variable.

Conversely if I have to change a configuration for every single run of the program than it should probably be an argument.

What happens if things live in a grey area? What should I pay attention to when deciding one or the other?

NOTE: I'm specifically working on a console program that might be daemonized down the road. I'm interested in this question in general, however.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nothing precludes command-line arguments from being used when starting a daemon, or configuration files from being used in interactive mode.

The general approach that works well and a lot of programs use is to have a list of prioritized ways to set program options:

1. Defaults
2. Global configurations (/etc or HKLM in the registry)
3. Local configurations (home directory or HKCU in the registry)
4. Environment variables
5. Program arguments
6. Options set while the program is running interactively

The program will start at step 1 and set values in each step, overriding previous values if applicable.

There is no reason this should work differently based on the program running interactively, in the background, at a command prompt, in a GUI, or as a daemon.

This is the way most experienced users and administrators will expect a program to work.

Comment: Another equivalent option is to go through the list in reverse order, at each step setting only those values which haven't already been set from another source. So you could implement it that way, if that were somehow easier.

Comment: User should be aware whether #5 may have an impact on #3.

Comment: Following the Unix tradition, #3.5 would be "environmental variables"

Comment: @progo good point, I missed that one. Edited to add it.

Comment: After answer edition, my previous comment should be edited to change #5 by #6.